# Pass two params in a Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controller, parameter-passing

I'm working on a project that requires a third party (not a registered user of my application) to follow an email link to update a document.  I've created a `:token` column for each entry, and have it successfully appended to the email link using:

```
edit_form_url(:id => @form.id, :token => @form.token)
```

My problem is trying to reference the additional param in my controller using this code:

```
def edit
    @form = Form.find(params[:id],[:token])
    redirect_to pages_error_path if @form.sign.present?
end
```

When using the above code, I get a `Couldn't find all Forms with 'id': (193, token) (found 1 results, but was looking for 2)` error.  Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I may have solved my own problem, posting it for Google and error checks:

```
  def edit
    @form = Form.find_by(token: params[:token], id: params[:id])
    redirect_to pages_error_path if @form.sign.present?
  end
```